# How to run file in background by adding variable

Tags: php

Hey PHP developers I am newbie. 
Today I want to run my `process.php` file in the background because it takes too much time to load... Here is the code that I want to use.

```
$proc=new BackgroundProcess();
$proc->setCmd('exec php <BASE_PATH>/process.php hello world');
$proc->start();
```

And I want to add this `ids=$postid&reaction=$reaction`  variable instead of hello world. 
And want to receive it with post in `process.php` file like this

```
$id =$_POST['ids'];
$type = $_POST['reaction'];
```

I am using this GitHub file 
https://github.com/pandasanjay/php-script-background-processer/blob/master/README.md

Before doing downvote answer me I am a newbie in PHP.

Comment: "_Before doing downvote answer me_" Answer what? I don't see a question here

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process

Comment: @kerbholz I want to add variable instead of hello world and receive it with get or post method in process.php

Comment: How to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) for this. If you want to pass parameters then try like this.

```
//it will store logs to log_data.log
exec("php process.php $id $type >log_data.log &");
```

Hope this will work for you :)

Try like this

```
   function execInBackground() {
       //this will run in background
       exec("php process.php $id $type > /dev/null &"); 
    }
```

Comment: $proc=new BackgroundProcess();
$proc->setCmd('exec("{PHP path} process.php $id $type >log_data.log &")');
$proc->start();

Comment: Do you mean this?

Comment: You can simply call 
`exec("php process.php $id $type >log_data.log &");`

Comment: Simply  can you plz elaborate

Comment: Check the updated answer if you are confused.

`function execInBackground() {
       //this will run in background
       exec("php process.php $id $type > /dev/null &"); 
    }`

Answer (score 0):

As soon as it is not HTTP request at all, you cannot access $_GET and $_POST superglobals. The right way to receive arguments in this case, is to access the array $argv. See official documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

---

**UPD:** And, well, if you really want to pass $_GET/$_POST params to this script executed via shell, here is a dirty trick:

```
$get_params_as_string = base64_encode(json_encode($_GET));
$proc=new BackgroundProcess();
$proc->setCmd("exec php <BASE_PATH>/process.php {$get_params_as_string}");
$proc->start();
```

And in your `process.php` access it like this:

```
$get_params = json_decode(base64_decode($argv[1]), true);
```

So, we are just created JSON from $_GET array. Then, as we know that JSON string contains special characters(like `"`, `{`, `}`, etc), and to avoid dealing with problems of escaping and unescaping, we simply encode this string as base64. It guarantees us absence of special characters in result string. Now we can use this string as a single argument, which we will pass to shell command (your BackgroundProcess). And finally, in `process.php` we can access this string from $args[1], then decode from base64, then decode from JSON to a regular PHP array. Here we go.

**This solution is provided only for educational purpose, please don't ever do it in real life.**